# How let github actions workflow push generated documentation to other repository in same organization using a bot name

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-actions

I am developing a python package in github. Under an organization in github I have two repositories `myorg/package` and `myorg/documentation`. The `package` repo contains the python package and the means to build the sphinx documentation and the `documentation` contains the generated static html published via github pages.

I am now setting up a github actions workflow to build the documentation in `package` and push it to `documentation` triggered by pushing a release tag to the `package` repo, but I am encountering problems with doing the push to `documentation` repo.

Ideally I would like to mark the commits as being made by a bot and I would like all with push-permission to both repositories to be able to run the workflow.

Here is my current workflow:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
          path: package
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: myorg/documentation
        path: documentation
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install tox tox-gh-actions
    - name: Build documentation
      run: |
        cd package
        tox -e apidoc
        tox -e docs
    - name: Publish documentation
      run: |
        cp -RT package/dist/docs/ documentation/latest/
        cd documentation
        git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
        git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
        git add -A
        git commit -m "Documentation update"
        git push
```

Running this fails on the final command with:

```
remote: Permission to pharmpy/pharmpy.github.io.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pharmpy/pharmpy.github.io/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am not so sure about the name and email of the bot. Some googling gave the impression that this belonged to some standard bot that could be used.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a solution:

1. Create a personal access token with repository access
2. Add this personal token as a github actions secret (I named it `PUSH_TOKEN`)
3. Use this token at checkout and when pushing

Here is the modified, working, version of the workflow:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
          path: package
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: myorg/documentation
        path: documentation
        token: ${{secrets.PUSH_TOKEN}}
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install tox tox-gh-actions
    - name: Build documentation
      run: |
        cd package
        tox -e apidoc
        tox -e docs
    - name: Publish documentation
      run: |
        cp -RT package/dist/docs/ documentation/latest/
        cd documentation
        git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
        git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
        git add -A
        git commit -m "Documentation update"
        git push https://$USERNAME:$REPO_KEY@github.com/myorg/documentation.git
      env:
        REPO_KEY: ${{secrets.PUSH_TOKEN}}
        USERNAME: github-actions[bot]
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

Note however there is a typo in the URL for the documentation git repo, fourth line from the end of the workflow:
`https:://$USER...` -> `https://$USER...`

Comment: Good catch @AlexMalins!

Comment: @RikardN, I use [actions/checkout@v3](https://github.com/actions/checkout) and I fix the same error by adding permission to write to contents. I've added another answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error can be fixed by adding write [permission](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) to repository content. I use [`actions/checkout@v3`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) and I didn't specify any tokens. The basic configuration for pushing commits looks like this:

```yaml
name: Example
on: workflow_dispatch
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        run: |
          date > 1.txt
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add 1.txt
          git commit -m updated
          git push
```

Comment: this pushes to the same repo, right? not a separate repo, which is what OP was asking for