# Permission denied to github-actions[bot]. The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, git-push

I want to push files into the current repository using Github Actions.

I've written a basic configuration that uses the official [`actions/checkout@v3`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action. My configuration is almost the same as in [the readme example](https://github.com/actions/checkout#push-a-commit-using-the-built-in-token):

```
name: Example
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        run: |
          date > 1.txt
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add 1.txt
          git commit -m updated
          git push
```

This configuration works well for any repository, except Github Pages repository. The error is:

```
remote: Permission to sirekanian/sirekanian.github.io.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sirekanian/sirekanian.github.io/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Why GitHub Pages repository differs from the ordinary one? Does the GitHub Pages repository have different permissions that do not allow to push into?

The most similar question I found is [How let github actions workflow push generated documentation to other repository in same organization using a bot name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997950). The answer was to use tokens, but I believe I should use a default token.

Answer (score 40):

You have to configure your repository - `Settings -> Action -> General -> Workflow permissions` and choose `read and write permissions`

Comment: For people using organization repos, it might have different setting at Organization's Settings. I changed there and it works now.

Comment: Keep in mind that this changes the default for all workflows in this repository. What you probably want, is to give more fine-grained permissions to just this workflow and only allow it to write to `content` (which tags falls under). Therefore, I suggest using the other answer to set the `permissions`.

Answer (score 16):

The permissions for `GITHUB_TOKEN` are read-only by default. If you want to push tags, you need to have `write` permissions to `contents`.

If you add a [permission](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) to write to contents, you will be able to push to your repository using GitHub checkout action:

```yaml
name: Example
on: workflow_dispatch
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  # your push job here
```